# How to create dialog like Uber use when we make a route

Tags: android

I'm using `GoogleMap` Api to create a maker with a title in a certain location, the problem is it just appears when I click in the marker, and I was wonder how they create this "dialog" exactly in this two locations!

I basically use this :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 15));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method on a `Marker` object called `showInfoWindow()` where you can explicitly show the Info window:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));

    marker.showInfoWindow();
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 15));
}
```

for reference [Info Window show/hide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#showhide_an_info_window)