# How to set a static distance when initialize the maps api on android

Tags: android, google-maps

When I get my actual position I add a Maker, but currently I added a animation to zoom-in to this location, but there's any way that when the map is launched, it doesn't make this animation but, it started already in zoom ?

That's what I have :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 15));
}
```

I want the zoom to be preset without an animation.

Comment: 15 is the camera zoom level, you can modify that to change the zoom level. Its kind of unclear what you are asking though...

Comment: @inner_class7 "I want the zoom to be preset without an animation." Pretty clear to me.

Comment: ahh, okay. Added an answer that changes camera position and zoom without the animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another convenience method in the `GoogleMap` class:

```
mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 15))
```

this will change the camera zoom and position without the animation.

Comment: Worked like charm! thanks. since we are here, could you see this thread ? I would appreciate! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43901443/how-to-create-dialog-like-uber-use-when-we-make-a-route